# IOS: viewcontroller with clear color

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a firstviewcontroller and i want to call a secondviewcontroller; this secondviewcontroller has its view in xib with a clearcolor and an semi-trasparent imageview, then I want to see firstviewcontroller under when i call this seconviewcontroller

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
    [secondViewController release];
```

then when I call it under my secondviewcontroller i don't see firstviewcontroller, but all white color...why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to see the first view controller, try adding the second one as a subview, and not by using presentModalViewController. The modal presentation is the problem. If you wish to achieve the modal animation effect, you're going to have to implement the animation manually. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Because of presentModalViewController::

use a navigationController instead.